# The right way to find SD-Card path and in work with its files

Tags: java, android, file, android-sdcard, sd-card

I am creating a file manager for android and the last thing I have to do is access to sd-card files.

And I have some questions about it.

1. I use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get **internal** storage path (`/storage/emulated/0/`). And as I know, it's not a right way because the method can return either internal storage or sd-card path. *So what is the right way to get internal storage?*
2. Also use the following code to get sd-card path:

   ```
   String sd = context.getExternalFilesDirs("")[1].getAbsolutePath();
   mPath = sd.substring(1,sd.indexOf("/Android/"));
   ```

With this code, I get the right way for sd but I can't work with files on sd-card (I get a permissions error but I have all necessary permissions).

So, the questions are: what are the correct ways of getting internal storage path and sd-card path on android (and how can I interact with sd-card files if File class doesn't work there)?

Comment: Since [nothing of what you have here will work on Android Q and beyond](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/06/07/death-external-storage-end-saga.html), you have significant problems, beyond the ones that you are already seeing. You might also wish to learn what the Android SDK refers to as [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/13/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html), and [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/15/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

Comment: In short, you have no filesystem access to arbitrary files on removable storage on Android 4.4+, and you have no filesystem access to arbitrary files on external storage on Android Q (by default) and Android R+ (for all apps). You are welcome to switch to using the Storage Access Framework and `DocumentFile` if you wish, though in truth file managers are now more of an OS-and-manufacturer thing.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have already tried SAF. I reveived the sd-card `Uri`. And getting names of files on sd-card, for example, worked very-very slowly. It took about 7-8 seconds to display all 33 files on sd-card

Comment: I am aware of that. File managers are now the responsibility of the OS and device manufacturers, not third-party developers such as yourself.

Comment: @CommonsWare ok, thank you for your answers :)

Comment: Note that 7-8 seconds seems slower than it should be. If you are using `DocumentFile` in a loop, look into using `DocumentsContract` more directly, to be able to get details about all immediate child documents of a tree in one query.